# can not draw anything on my canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

same code i've written to make a canvas drawing board behaving differently .don't know what happeded.i have wrote the same  codes before that worked fine  but it is not allowing me to draw a single thing this time.what might go wrong ?

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
var candraw=false;
var x,y;
var i=0;
var radius=10;

function canvloder(){
    var canvas=document.getElementById("mycanv");
    canvas.width=500;
    canvas.height=700;
    canvas.style.border="1px solid black";
    canvas.style.position="absolute";
    canvas.style.left="270px";
    canvas.style.top="30px";
    canvas.style.backgroundColor="yellow";
    canvas.addEventListener("click",function(e){candraw(e)},false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove",function(e){nowdraw(e)},false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mouseout",function(e){cannotdraw(e)},false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mouseup",function(e){cannotdraw(e)},false);
}

function candraw(e){
    candraw=true;
}

function nowdraw(e){
    var ctx=document.getElementById("mycanv").getContext("2d");
    x=e.offsetX||e.layerX||0;
    y=e.offsetY||e.layerY||0;

    if(candraw){
        if(i==0){
            ctx.strokeStyle="red";
            ctx.lineTo(x,y);
            ctx.stroke();
        }

        if(i>0){
            ctx.fillStyle="red";
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(x,y,radius,0,2*Math.PI);
            ctx.fill();

           i=0;
        }

        ctx.fillStyle="red";
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x,y,radius,0,2*Math.PI);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.lineWidth=2*radius;
        ctx.strokeStyle="red";

        ctx.moveTo(x,y);

    }

}

function cannotdraw(){
    candraw=false;
    i++;
}

window.onload=canvloder;
</script>
<canvas id="mycanv" ></canvas>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: one is for mouse out from the canvas and other for mousekey up while i am in the canvas(so that until u click the mouse button you can not draw and to draw u have to hold down the mouse button while you move it ).it is ok .i have used it in other codes

Answer (score 1):

```
var candraw=false;

function candraw(e){
    candraw=true;
}
```

So... what is `candraw`? Is it a Function or a Boolean? Once you overwrote `candraw` with `false` in `cannotdraw`, `candraw` is no longer a function.

Any way, this two functions are quite useless and should not even exist in the first place as two separate functions. You might want to do something like this:

```
function setDrawable(bool){
    candraw = bool;
}
```